# How to get properties of object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection

```
class ClassB:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = "b"
        self.__b = "__b"

    @property
    def propertyB(self):
        return "B"
```

I know `getattr,hasattr...` can access the property.
But why don't have the `iterattr` or `listattr`?

Expect result of `ClassB` object:

```
{'propertyB': 'B'}
```

Expect result of `ClassB` class:

```
['propertyB']
```

Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga 's comment.
`vars(obj)` and `vars(obj.__class__)` is different!

Comment: To get the attributes of an object, use `vars(obj)`. Note, `property` objects belong to the *class* not the *instance*

Comment: And note, your `property` doesn't know that it will always return `B`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if I know the name of property, I can get the value by `getattr`

Comment: whata if your property returns `random.random()`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In that case, I think the value shall be same as `getattr(b_object, 'randomProperty')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built-in [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) as follows:

```
properties = []
for k,v in vars(ClassB).items():
    if type(v) is property:
        properties.append(k)
```

Using a list-comprehension:

```py
>>> [k for k,v in vars(ClassB).items() if type(v) is property]
['propertyB']
```

Answer (score 1):

To list propeties of a python Class you can use **__dict__**

Example

```
>>> class C(object):
x = 4

>>> c = C()
>>> c.y = 5
>>> c.__dict__
{'y': 5}
```

See this link for more examples and information - https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2016/06/09/the-magic-behind-attribute-access-in-python/